# how to assign a group of computers to a specific scope

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp

I have a Windows 2008 server with the DHCP role installed. All the computers (except the servers) get their IP addresses automatically from  one scope. I would like to assign several of computers to a different scope.

How do I make sure that the said computers receive IP addresses only from the new scope I'm about to create?

**NOTE:** Also I want to make sure that the rest of the computers continue to receive their addresses from the old scope alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can add DHCP reservations for each client but that requiers you to enter the MAC adddress of each client. Another way of doing this is dividing the network into multiple subnets and addin a scope for each subnet..